# How to generate Zipf distributed numbers efficiently?

Tags: c++, random

I'm currently benchmarking some data structures in C++ and I want to test them when working on Zipf-distributed numbers.

I'm using the generator provided on this site: http://www.cse.usf.edu/~christen/tools/toolpage.html

I adapted the implementation to use a Mersenne Twister generator.

It works well but it is really slow. In my case, the range can be big (about a million) and the number of random numbers generate can be several millions.

The alpha parameter does not change over time, it is fixed.

I tried to precaculate all the sum_prob. It's much faster, but still slows on big range.

Is there a faster way to generate Zipf distributed numbers ? Even something less precise will be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Does `alpha` have a different value for each call to `zipf()`, or does it have the same value each time you call the function?

Comment: The alpha parameter have the same value each time I call the function.

Comment: Are you still interested in a more efficient solution to this problem?

Comment: I don't need it anymore, but if there is a more efficient solution, I'm still interested :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pre-calculation alone does not help so much. But as it's obvious the sum_prob is accumulative and has ascending order. So if we use a binary-search to find the zipf_value we would decrease the order of generating a Zipf distributed number from O(n) to O(log(n)). Which is so much improvement in efficiency.
Here it is, just replace the `zipf()` function in `genzipf.c` with following one:

```
int zipf(double alpha, int n)
{
  static int first = TRUE;      // Static first time flag
  static double c = 0;          // Normalization constant
  static double *sum_probs;     // Pre-calculated sum of probabilities
  double z;                     // Uniform random number (0 < z < 1)
  int zipf_value;               // Computed exponential value to be returned
  int    i;                     // Loop counter
  int low, high, mid;           // Binary-search bounds

  // Compute normalization constant on first call only
  if (first == TRUE)
  {
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
      c = c + (1.0 / pow((double) i, alpha));
    c = 1.0 / c;

    sum_probs = malloc((n+1)*sizeof(*sum_probs));
    sum_probs[0] = 0;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
      sum_probs[i] = sum_probs[i-1] + c / pow((double) i, alpha);
    }
    first = FALSE;
  }

  // Pull a uniform random number (0 < z < 1)
  do
  {
    z = rand_val(0);
  }
  while ((z == 0) || (z == 1));

  // Map z to the value
  low = 1, high = n, mid;
  do {
    mid = floor((low+high)/2);
    if (sum_probs[mid] >= z && sum_probs[mid-1] < z) {
      zipf_value = mid;
      break;
    } else if (sum_probs[mid] >= z) {
      high = mid-1;
    } else {
      low = mid+1;
    }
  } while (low <= high);

  // Assert that zipf_value is between 1 and N
  assert((zipf_value >=1) && (zipf_value <= n));

  return(zipf_value);
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's really nice! I just benchmarked both versions and yours is indeed much faster than the base version and much faster than mine. And it seems like the distribution is correct. Thanks a lot.

Comment: OK, so sum_probs here is the "cumulative distribution function", and at least one blog post talks about how to compute it faster/better.  The mid-point bisection will work in log(n) s claimed, but one can even do better by replacing it with Newton-Rapheson method... the CDF is so smooth, you don't need bisection.

Comment: `zipf_value` variable is uninitialized. Is it possible that `while (low <= high)` becomes false ? If yes, the function will return a garbage result in this case. If it can never be true, then the test can be dropped and the `do while` loop can be replaced with a `for(;;)` loop.

Comment: Dear @chmike, no it's not possible since the `sum_probs` is a cumulative array of probabilities and we will always find the `z` value somewhere in it. Also note that the original function implementation has an assertion on the `zipf_value` (I didn't add this part) just before returning it. So garbage result is not possible at all.

Answer (score 6):

The only C++11 Zipf random generator I could find calculated the probabilities explicitly and used `std::discrete_distribution`.  This works fine for small ranges, but is not useful if you need to generate Zipf values with a very wide range (for database testing, in my case) since it will exhaust memory.  So, I implemented the below-mentioned algorithm in C++.

I have not rigorously tested this code, and some optimizations are probably possible, but it only requires constant space and seems to work well.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>

/** Zipf-like random distribution.
 *
 * "Rejection-inversion to generate variates from monotone discrete
 * distributions", Wolfgang Hörmann and Gerhard Derflinger
 * ACM TOMACS 6.3 (1996): 169-184
 */
template<class IntType = unsigned long, class RealType = double>
class zipf_distribution
{
public:
    typedef RealType input_type;
    typedef IntType result_type;

    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<IntType>::is_integer, "");
    static_assert(!std::numeric_limits<RealType>::is_integer, "");

    zipf_distribution(const IntType n=std::numeric_limits<IntType>::max(),
                      const RealType q=1.0)
        : n(n)
        , q(q)
        , H_x1(H(1.5) - 1.0)
        , H_n(H(n + 0.5))
        , dist(H_x1, H_n)
    {}

    IntType operator()(std::mt19937& rng)
    {
        while (true) {
            const RealType u = dist(rng);
            const RealType x = H_inv(u);
            const IntType  k = clamp<IntType>(std::round(x), 1, n);
            if (u >= H(k + 0.5) - h(k)) {
                return k;
            }
        }
    }

private:
    /** Clamp x to [min, max]. */
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr T clamp(const T x, const T min, const T max)
    {
        return std::max(min, std::min(max, x));
    }

    /** exp(x) - 1 / x */
    static double
    expxm1bx(const double x)
    {
        return (std::abs(x) > epsilon)
            ? std::expm1(x) / x
            : (1.0 + x/2.0 * (1.0 + x/3.0 * (1.0 + x/4.0)));
    }

    /** H(x) = log(x) if q == 1, (x^(1-q) - 1)/(1 - q) otherwise.
     * H(x) is an integral of h(x).
     *
     * Note the numerator is one less than in the paper order to work with all
     * positive q.
     */
    const RealType H(const RealType x)
    {
        const RealType log_x = std::log(x);
        return expxm1bx((1.0 - q) * log_x) * log_x;
    }

    /** log(1 + x) / x */
    static RealType
    log1pxbx(const RealType x)
    {
        return (std::abs(x) > epsilon)
            ? std::log1p(x) / x
            : 1.0 - x * ((1/2.0) - x * ((1/3.0) - x * (1/4.0)));
    }

    /** The inverse function of H(x) */
    const RealType H_inv(const RealType x)
    {
        const RealType t = std::max(-1.0, x * (1.0 - q));
        return std::exp(log1pxbx(t) * x);
    }

    /** That hat function h(x) = 1 / (x ^ q) */
    const RealType h(const RealType x)
    {
        return std::exp(-q * std::log(x));
    }

    static constexpr RealType epsilon = 1e-8;

    IntType                                  n;     ///< Number of elements
    RealType                                 q;     ///< Exponent
    RealType                                 H_x1;  ///< H(x_1)
    RealType                                 H_n;   ///< H(n)
    std::uniform_real_distribution<RealType> dist;  ///< [H(x_1), H(n)]
};
```

Comment: Excellent! FWIW, the above code seems to work as expected.  For small array sizes, though, the `std::vector pdf` plus `std::discrete_distribution` is about 2.2x faster, (for me), where "small" is N=300.

Comment: @Linas the code is not the same as in the paper by purpose, because the original algorithm does not support exponents <= 1. Could you please give parameter values for which the Java algorithm is wrong? I would be very interested, as it was me who modified the original algorithm to support any exponents and implemented the algorithm in Apache Commons Math. I have also implemented a Python version together with a set of unit tests here: https://github.com/oertl/zipf-random-paper

Comment: Argh... I have to retract my comments above! I was porting the C++ code to scheme, dropped a minus sign, got bad results, got very confused. I found the minus sign today, and am now erasing my comments. The C++ code, as posted, looks good. I've just run it through new, more comprehensive unit tests. By extension, I guess the java is good too. To be clear, I'm testing my code here: https://github.com/opencog/cogutil/blob/master/opencog/util/zipf.h

Comment: p.s. I can double performance (and still pass unit tests) by adding the following: `doucle cut=1.0 - H_inv( H(1.5) - h(1.0)); if (k - x <= cut) return k;` .. FYI.

Comment: And one last note: I've extended the code to handle non-zero Hurwicz q (as in "q-series") but I find that the `expxm1bx` and `log1pxbx` blows up for anything except the very smallest `q` values. By contrast, the original Hörmann & Derflinger code works great for q into the millions. (They call it "v" not "q"; they mistakenly used "q" for "s" and the C++ code duplicated that error...in number theory and string theory, the deformation is always called "q" and not "v", so bad nomenclature adds to the confusion.)

Answer (score 3):

The following line in your code is executed `n` times for each call to `zipf()`:

```
sum_prob = sum_prob + c / pow((double) i, alpha);
```

It is regrettable that it is necessary to call the `pow()` function because, internally, this function sums not one but two Taylor series [considering that `pow(x, alpha) == exp(alpha*log(x))`].  If `alpha` is an integer, of course, then you can speed the code up a lot by replacing `pow()` with simple multiplication.  If `alpha` is a rational number, then you may be able to speed the code up to a lesser degree by coding a Newton-Raphson iteration to take the place of the two Taylor series.  If the last condition holds, please advise.

Fortunately, you have indicated that `alpha` does not change.  Can you not speed the code up a lot by preparing a table of `pow((double) i, alpha)`, then letting `zipf()` look numbers up the table?  That way, `zipf()` would not have to call `pow()` at all.  I suspect that this would save significant time.

Yet further improvements are possible.  What if you factored a function `sumprob()` out of `zipf()`?  Could you not prepare an even more aggressive look-up table for `sumprob()`'s use?

Maybe some of these ideas will move you in the right direction.  See what you cannot do with them.

*Update:*  I see that your question as now revised may not be able to use this answer.  From the present point, your question may resolve into a question in complex variable theory.  Such are often not easy questions, as you know.  It may be that a sufficiently clever mathematician has discovered a relevant recurrence relation or some trick like the *normal* distribution's Box-Muller technique but, if so, I am not acquainted with the technique.  Good luck.  (It probably does not matter to you but, in case it does, the late N. N. Lebedev's excellent 1972 book *Special Functions and Their Applications* is available in English translation from the Russian in an inexpensive paperback edition.  If you *really, really* wanted to crack this problem, you might read Lebedev next -- but, of course, that is a desperate measure, isn't it?)

Comment: AFAICT most decent `pow` implementations are already optimized for the case where `alpha` is an integer.

Comment: I tried to precalculate all the sumprob in an array for each i in [0,N] but even if it's much faster, it is not enough when the range is high. If the range is 1000000, each time next is called, it can loop up to 1000000 times... 

Yes, the second measure is a bit desperate, I hope I will found another solution before.

Answer (score 3):

As a complement to the very nice rejection-inversion implementation given above, here's a C++ class, with the same API, that is simpler and faster *for a small number of bins, only*. On my machine, its about 2.3x faster for N=300. It's faster because it performs a direct table lookup, instead of computing logs and powers.  The table eats cache, though... Making a guess based on the size of my CPU's d-cache, I imagine that the proper rejection-inversion algo given above will become faster for something around N=35K, maybe.  Also, initializing the table requires a call to `std::pow()` for each bin, so this wins performance only if you are drawing more than N values out of it. Otherwise, rejection-inversion is faster. Choose wisely.

(I've set up the API so it looks a lot like what the std::c++ standards committee might come up with.)

```
/**
 * Example usage:
 *
 *    std::random_device rd;
 *    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
 *    zipf_table_distribution<> zipf(300);
 *
 *    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
 *        printf("draw %d %d\n", i, zipf(gen));
 */
template<class IntType = unsigned long, class RealType = double>
class zipf_table_distribution
{
   public:
      typedef IntType result_type;

      static_assert(std::numeric_limits<IntType>::is_integer, "");
      static_assert(!std::numeric_limits<RealType>::is_integer, "");

      /// zipf_table_distribution(N, s)
      /// Zipf distribution for `N` items, in the range `[1,N]` inclusive.
      /// The distribution follows the power-law 1/n^s with exponent `s`.
      /// This uses a table-lookup, and thus provides values more
      /// quickly than zipf_distribution. However, the table can take
      /// up a considerable amount of RAM, and initializing this table
      /// can consume significant time.
      zipf_table_distribution(const IntType n,
                              const RealType q=1.0) :
         _n(init(n,q)),
         _q(q),
         _dist(_pdf.begin(), _pdf.end())
      {}
      void reset() {}

      IntType operator()(std::mt19937& rng)
      {
         return _dist(rng);
      }

      /// Returns the parameter the distribution was constructed with.
      RealType s() const { return _q; }
      /// Returns the minimum value potentially generated by the distribution.
      result_type min() const { return 1; }
      /// Returns the maximum value potentially generated by the distribution.
      result_type max() const { return _n; }

   private:
      std::vector<RealType>               _pdf;  ///< Prob. distribution
      IntType                             _n;    ///< Number of elements
      RealType                            _q;    ///< Exponent
      std::discrete_distribution<IntType> _dist; ///< Draw generator

      /** Initialize the probability mass function */
      IntType init(const IntType n, const RealType q)
      {
         _pdf.reserve(n+1);
         _pdf.emplace_back(0.0);
         for (IntType i=1; i<=n; i++)
            _pdf.emplace_back(std::pow((double) i, -q));
         return n;
      }
};
```

Comment: Great, thanks for clarifying the trade-offs.  I wrote the above for extremely large distributions, but this approach is simpler and I agree it makes more sense for relatively small ones (which is probably most, I imagine doing this sort of thing in the billions isn't very common).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version that is 2x faster than drobilla's original post, plus it also supports non-zero deformation parameter `q` (aka Hurwicz q, q-series q or quantum group deformation q) and changes notation to conform to standard usage in number theory textbooks. Rigorously tested; see unit tests at https://github.com/opencog/cogutil/blob/master/tests/util/zipfUTest.cxxtest

Dual license MIT license, or Gnu Affero, please copy into the C++ standard as desired.

```
/**
 * Zipf (Zeta) random distribution.
 *
 * Implementation taken from drobilla's May 24, 2017 answer to
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983239/how-to-generate-zipf-distributed-numbers-efficiently
 *
 * That code is referenced with this:
 * "Rejection-inversion to generate variates from monotone discrete
 * distributions", Wolfgang Hörmann and Gerhard Derflinger
 * ACM TOMACS 6.3 (1996): 169-184
 *
 * Note that the Hörmann & Derflinger paper, and the stackoverflow
 * code base incorrectly names the paramater as `q`, when they mean `s`.
 * Thier `q` has nothing to do with the q-series. The names in the code
 * below conform to conventions.
 *
 * Example usage:
 *
 *    std::random_device rd;
 *    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
 *    zipf_distribution<> zipf(300);
 *
 *    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
 *        printf("draw %d %d\n", i, zipf(gen));
 */

template<class IntType = unsigned long, class RealType = double>
class zipf_distribution
{
   public:
      typedef IntType result_type;

      static_assert(std::numeric_limits<IntType>::is_integer, "");
      static_assert(!std::numeric_limits<RealType>::is_integer, "");

      /// zipf_distribution(N, s, q)
      /// Zipf distribution for `N` items, in the range `[1,N]` inclusive.
      /// The distribution follows the power-law 1/(n+q)^s with exponent
      /// `s` and Hurwicz q-deformation `q`.
      zipf_distribution(const IntType n=std::numeric_limits<IntType>::max(),
                        const RealType s=1.0,
                        const RealType q=0.0)
         : n(n)
         , _s(s)
         , _q(q)
         , oms(1.0-s)
         , spole(abs(oms) < epsilon)
         , rvs(spole ? 0.0 : 1.0/oms)
         , H_x1(H(1.5) - h(1.0))
         , H_n(H(n + 0.5))
         , cut(1.0 - H_inv(H(1.5) - h(1.0)))
         , dist(H_x1, H_n)
      {
         if (-0.5 >= q)
            throw std::runtime_error("Range error: Parameter q must be greater than -0.5!");
      }
      void reset() {}

      IntType operator()(std::mt19937& rng)
      {
         while (true)
         {
            const RealType u = dist(rng);
            const RealType x = H_inv(u);
            const IntType  k = std::round(x);
            if (k - x <= cut) return k;
            if (u >= H(k + 0.5) - h(k))
               return k;
         }
      }

      /// Returns the parameter the distribution was constructed with.
      RealType s() const { return _s; }
      /// Returns the Hurwicz q-deformation parameter.
      RealType q() const { return _q; }
      /// Returns the minimum value potentially generated by the distribution.
      result_type min() const { return 1; }
      /// Returns the maximum value potentially generated by the distribution.
      result_type max() const { return n; }


   private:
      IntType    n;     ///< Number of elements
      RealType   _s;    ///< Exponent
      RealType   _q;    ///< Deformation
      RealType   oms;   ///< 1-s
      bool       spole; ///< true if s near 1.0
      RealType   rvs;   ///< 1/(1-s)
      RealType   H_x1;  ///< H(x_1)
      RealType   H_n;   ///< H(n)
      RealType   cut;   ///< rejection cut
      std::uniform_real_distribution<RealType> dist;  ///< [H(x_1), H(n)]

      // This provides 16 decimal places of precision,
      // i.e. good to (epsilon)^4 / 24 per expanions log, exp below.
      static constexpr RealType epsilon = 2e-5;

      /** (exp(x) - 1) / x */
      static double
      expxm1bx(const double x)
      {
         if (std::abs(x) > epsilon)
            return std::expm1(x) / x;
         return (1.0 + x/2.0 * (1.0 + x/3.0 * (1.0 + x/4.0)));
      }

      /** log(1 + x) / x */
      static RealType
      log1pxbx(const RealType x)
      {
         if (std::abs(x) > epsilon)
            return std::log1p(x) / x;
         return 1.0 - x * ((1/2.0) - x * ((1/3.0) - x * (1/4.0)));
      }
      /**
       * The hat function h(x) = 1/(x+q)^s
       */
      const RealType h(const RealType x)
      {
         return std::pow(x + _q, -_s);
      }

      /**
       * H(x) is an integral of h(x).
       *     H(x) = [(x+q)^(1-s) - (1+q)^(1-s)] / (1-s)
       * and if s==1 then
       *     H(x) = log(x+q) - log(1+q)
       *
       * Note that the numerator is one less than in the paper
       * order to work with all s. Unfortunately, the naive
       * implementation of the above hits numerical underflow
       * when q is larger than 10 or so, so we split into
       * different regimes.
       *
       * When q != 0, we shift back to what the paper defined:

       *    H(x) = (x+q)^{1-s} / (1-s)
       * and for q != 0 and also s==1, use
       *    H(x) = [exp{(1-s) log(x+q)} - 1] / (1-s)
       */
      const RealType H(const RealType x)
      {
         if (not spole)
            return std::pow(x + _q, oms) / oms;

         const RealType log_xpq = std::log(x + _q);
         return log_xpq * expxm1bx(oms * log_xpq);
      }

      /**
       * The inverse function of H(x).
       *    H^{-1}(y) = [(1-s)y + (1+q)^{1-s}]^{1/(1-s)} - q
       * Same convergence issues as above; two regimes.
       *
       * For s far away from 1.0 use the paper version
       *    H^{-1}(y) = -q + (y(1-s))^{1/(1-s)}
       */
      const RealType H_inv(const RealType y)
      {
         if (not spole)
            return std::pow(y * oms, rvs) - _q;

         return std::exp(y * log1pxbx(oms * y)) - _q;
      }
};
```

Comment: I also wrote an equivalent for scheme, see srfi-194 See https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-194/srfi-194.html

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime there is a faster way based on rejection inversion sampling, see code [here](https://github.com/apache/commons-math/blob/138f84bfa5d36c8f6e2825640af1ed82daa9dc1d/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math4/distribution/ZipfDistribution.java).

Comment: Please put the answer explicitly in your response instead of redirecting to a link. The link can disappear and leave your response unhelpful.