# Random ints with different likelihoods

Tags: c++, random

I was wondering if there was a way to have a random number between A an b and where if a number meets a certain requirement it is more likely to appear than all the other numbers between A and B, for example: Lower numbers are more likely to appear so if A = 1 and B = 10 then 1 would be the likeliest and 10 would be the unlikeliest.

All help is appreciated :) (sorry for bad English/grammar/question)

Comment: Are you looking for zipf distribution ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983239/how-to-generate-zipf-distributed-numbers-efficiently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 (which you should absolutely be using by now) added the `<random>` header to the C++ standard library. This header provides much higher quality random number generators to C++. Using `srand()` and `rand()` has never been a very good idea because there's no guarantee of quality, but now it's truly inexcusable.

In your example, it sounds like you want what would probably be called a 'discrete triangular distribution': the probability mass function looks like a triangle. The easiest (but perhaps not the most efficient) way to implement this in C++ would be the discrete distribution included in `<random>`:

```
auto discrete_triangular_distribution(int max) {
    std::vector<int> weights(max);
    std::iota(weights.begin(), weights.end(), 0);
    std::discrete_distribution<> dist(weights.begin(), weights.end());
    return dist;
}

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    auto&& dist = discrete_triangular_distribution(10);
    std::map<int, int> counts;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        ++counts[dist(gen)];
    for (auto count: counts)
        std::cout << count.first << " generated ";
        std::cout << count.second << " times.\n";
}
```

which for me gives the following output:

```
1 generated 233 times.
2 generated 425 times.
3 generated 677 times.
4 generated 854 times.
5 generated 1130 times.
6 generated 1334 times.
7 generated 1565 times.
8 generated 1804 times.
9 generated 1978 times.
```

Things more complex than this would be better served with either using one of the existing distributions (I have been told that all commonly used statistical distributions are included) or by writing your own distribution, which isn't too hard: it just has to be an object with a function call operator that takes a random bit generator and uses those bits to produce (in this case) random numbers. But you could create one that made random strings, or any arbitrary random objects, perhaps for testing purposes).

Comment: From the question it seems that the outputs should be in the range *[1, 10]*, and that lower numbers should be *more* likely.

Comment: It's just an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I just changed:  ++counts[dist(gen)];   to   ++counts[abs(10 - dist(gen))];  to make the lower numbers more likely :)

Comment: @MilesRout Hey I've been using your random distribution for my project however I have the problem that whenever the numbers from 0 - 2 are entered the program crashes, is there an easy way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't specify which distribution to use. One option (of many) is to use the [(negative) exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). This distribution is parameterized by a parameter *λ*. For each value of *λ*, the maximum result is unbounded (which needs to be handled in order to return results only in the range specified)

[image]

(from Wikipedia, By Skbkekas, CC BY 3.0)

so any *λ* could theoretically work; however, the properties of the CDF

[image]

(from Wikipedia, By Skbkekas, CC BY 3.0)

imply that it pays to choose something in the order of *1 / (to - from + 1)*.

The following class works like a standard library distribution. Internally, it generates numbers in a loop, until a result in *[from, to]* is obtained.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <random>

class bounded_discrete_exponential_dist {
public: 
    explicit bounded_discrete_exponential_dist(std::size_t from, std::size_t to) : 
        m_from{from}, m_to{to}, m_d{0.5 / (to - from + 1)} {}
    explicit bounded_discrete_exponential_dist(std::size_t from, std::size_t to, double factor) : 
        m_from{from}, m_to{to}, m_d{factor} {}

    template<class Gen>
    std::size_t operator()(Gen &gen) {
        while(true) {
            const auto r = m_from + static_cast<std::size_t>(m_d(gen));
            if(r <= m_to)   
                return r;
        }
    }

private:
    std::size_t m_from, m_to;
    std::exponential_distribution<> m_d;
};
```

Here is an example of using it:

```
int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    bounded_discrete_exponential_dist d{1, 10};

    std::vector<std::size_t> hist(10, 0);
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 99999; ++i)
        ++hist[d(gen) - 1];

    for(auto h: hist)
        std::cout << std::string(static_cast<std::size_t>(80 * h / 99999.), '+') << std::endl;
}
```

When run, it outputs a histogram like this:

```
$ ./a.out
++++++++++
+++++++++
+++++++++
++++++++
+++++++
+++++++
+++++++
+++++++
++++++
++++++
```

Comment: Really nice answer, however I thought @Miles ' answer suited my needs a bit better.

Comment: @AdminBenni That's fine. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic random number generator should produce a high-quality, uniform random numbers on 0 to 1 - epsilon. You then transform it to get the distribution you want. The simplest transform is of course (int) ( p * N) in the common case of needing an integer on 0 to N -1.

But there are many many other transforms you can try. Take the square root, for example, to bias it to 1.0, then 1 - p to set the bias towards zero. Or you can look up the Poisson distribution, which might be what you are after. You can also use a half-Gaussian distribution (statistical bell curve with the zero entries cut off, and presumably also the extreme tail of the distribution as it goes out of range).

There can be no right answer. Try various things, plot out ten thousand or so values, and pick the one that gives results you like.

Answer (score -1):

You can make an array of values, the more likely value has more indexes and then choose a random index.

example:

```
int random[55];
int result;

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; ++i)
       for (int j = i ; j <= 10 ; ++j)
          random[index++] = i;

result = random[rand() % 55];
```

Also, you can try to get random number twice, first time you choose the max number then you choose your random number:

```
int max= rand() % 10 + 1; // This is your max value
int random = rand() %  max + 1; // This is you result
```

Both ways will make 1 more likely than 2 , 2 more likely than 3 ... 9 more likely than 10.

Comment: Yes it is. Everyone question wants the correct solution.